# Website moves when broswer resizes ? Everything out of place?

Tags: html, css

So, in the final weeks I have to send this project we have been working on for school. Today however, I uploaded live to http://goroam.org and was shocked when I realized that everything was pushed around, and out of place. I know that the font's look really bad but I wasn't done uploading the font's because of the issue that i'm trying to fix now. Also why is there a horizontal scroll bar? I'm so confused. Any help will be gladly taken..

Comment: did u use html,body{margin:0; padding:0;}

Comment: yes thats in my css why do you ask?

Comment: @user3602329 - your link doesn't work.

Comment: Place your data inside the content class

Answer (score 0):

from your dastyle.css remove
    **width: 100%;** 
which you have assign in body and add
    **position: absolute;**
example

```
body{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **CSS3** and stay trouble free :

```
div
{
 resize:both;
 overflow:auto;
}
```

**(or) without CSS3**

Just drop you width and :

```
body{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```